# Simple question about Kahler polarization

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, holomorphic-bundles

**Differential geometry:**
Let $S$ be a Kahler surface. That is a 4 real dimensional surface or a complex 2 dimensional one. Since by definition $S$ is complex it comes equipped with a Kahler 2-form $J$. If we choose a coordinate patch with holomorphic coordinates $z, w$ in some neighborhood $U$, then we can write the Kahler form locally as 
$$
J = f_{z,\bar{z}} \, dz  \wedge d\bar{z} + f_{z,\bar{w}}\, dz  \wedge d\bar{w} + f_{w,\bar{z}}\, dw  \wedge d\bar{z}   + f_{w,\bar{w}}\, dw  \wedge d\bar{w} 
$$ 
**Algebraic geometry:** Assume from now on that $S$ is also a complex algebraic variety, say $\mathbb{CP}^2$ or some Hirzebruch surface. Then $[J] \in H^2(S,\mathbb{Z})$. Then $[J]$ is also called a polarization, or an ample class and belongs to $\mathcal{O}_S(1)$. The object $\mathcal{O}_S(1)$ is the twisting sheaf over $S$ and sections of it are monomials of degree 1.

**My question:** *Does this simply tell me that the functions $f$ have no poles and they have to be either $z$, $w$, $\bar{z}$ or $\bar w$ (only monomials of degree 1)? And how do we see the "ample" nature of this line bundle from its diffential geometric definition?*

If not, what am I missing here? Clearly the line bundle associated to $\mathcal{O}_1(S)$ locally defined by the combinations $da \wedge d\bar{b}$ where $a,b=z,w$.

Comment: The degree $1$ monomials that are sections of $\mathcal O_S(1)$ are the homogeneous coordinates of the associated projective embedding, which don't have anything in particular to do with the local coordinates in which you wrote the Kahler form. In terms of ampleness, I believe you want to look at a metric on the line bundle which is induced by the Kahler form, and then ampleness is equivalent to positivity of the associated curvature form (that is to say, the curvature of the Chern connection of the metric on the bundle).

Comment: So how can one make the connection that $J \in \Omega^{1,1}(S)$ on the diff. geometry side and it is also a line bundle, and the fact that $J \in \mathcal{O}_S(1)$ on the other side. Surely, there must be some connection. Usually, say for vector bundles and locally free sheaves one gets that the transition functions of the former are the sections of the latter.

Comment: First, a Kähler structure is *stronger* than a complex structure, so your third sentence is wrong. A complex surface need not be a Kähler manifold. That said, the coefficients $h_{i\bar j}$ of the Kähler form $\frac{\sqrt{-1}}2 \sum h_{i\bar j}dz^i\wedge d\bar z^j$ are *smooth* but definitely not (even locally) holomorphic or antiholomorphic. The Kähler metric you started with need not come from an ample line bundle (or embedding in $\Bbb P^N$). If it does, as you seem to be assuming, then the Kähler form is the restriction of the Kähler form on the ambient $\Bbb P^N$.

Comment: You are right, I wanted to begin with a Kahler manifold in the first place.